# Nullspace and Rangespace problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so I have been trying to solve a problem but can't really figure out how.

Here is the question: Let $T: \mathcal P_3 \to M_{2\times2}$ be a linear transformation defined by:
$$T\big(p(x)\big) = \begin{bmatrix}\space\space\space\space\space\space p(0)\ \space\space  p'(0)\\p''(0)\ \space\space\space\space0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Here $\mathcal P_3$ is the set of all polynomials of degree at most three.

The first question asks us to find the general formula for  $T\big(p(x)\big)$ with $p(x)= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,a\not=0$, which I found to be  $$\begin{bmatrix}d\ \space\space\space c\\ 2b\ \space\space0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then we are asked to find the null space $N(T)$ and range space $R(T)$

I know what both of them mean but I can't figure out how to obtain them in this particular problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, the image of an arbitrary element of $\mathcal P_3$ is a matrix of the form $\small{\begin{bmatrix}d&c\\2b&0\end{bmatrix}}$. That is to say, the range of $T$ consists of all matrices of this form, with arbitrary parameters $b$, $c$ and $d$. Can you find a basis for this space?

Similarly, the kernel of $T$ is the set of polynomials $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that $$T(p(x)) = \begin{bmatrix}d&c\\2b&0\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$ It should be obvious that this forces $b=c=d=0$. I’m sure that you can complete the description of the nullspace from here.

Answer (score 0):

Null space= $\{p(x)|T(p(x))=0\}\implies$ Null space=$ \{p(x)|p(0)=p'(0)=p''(0)=0 \}. $ Now you can write the null space!

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. This is what I thought, but doesn't that make that the Nullspace is empty?